# Prove that there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq n|x-a|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $a\in[0,1]$. Prove that there exists an integer $n\geq1$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|\leq n|x-a|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

I know that $f'(a)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. From this I could not proceed. Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: I really doubt this is true. If the claim were true, $f$ would be differentiable almost everywhere, and the given hypothesis is differentiability at a single point

Comment: Will you please edit the title of your post into something that makes sense?

Comment: Rubi76re, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is a very low-quality question and does not match the policy of this siteweb.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)-f'(a)|<\epsilon$.  So, pick $\epsilon:=1$.  You can split $[0, 1]$ into two pieces, one where $|x-a|< \delta$ and the other where $|x-a|\ge\delta$.

If $|x-a|<\delta$ and $x\ne a$, $(f(x)-f(a))/(x-a)$ must be in the range $[f'(a)-1,f'(a)+1]$, so its absolute value is no more than $|f'(a)|+1$, i.e., $|f(x)-f(a)|\le (|f'(a)|+1)|x-a|$.  This is also clearly true if $x=a$.

If $|x-a|\ge\delta$, you can use the fact that, since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, $f$ has a minimum and a maximum, $m$ and $M$, say, on $[0,1]$.  So $|f(x)-f(a)|$ is no more than $M-m$, and since $|x-a|\ge\delta$, $M-m\le ((M-m)/\delta)|x-a|$, so $|f(x)-f(a)|\le ((M-m)/\delta)|x-a|$.

Combining the two pieces, you can see that picking any integer $n\ge 1$ so that $n\ge \max(|f'(a)|+1, (M-m)/\delta)$ will work.

Comment: David Moews, please do not answer very low-quality questions anymore !